# Custom cleaning form data in django

Tags: django, forms, validation

I know how to clean data in django's forms.py but I am running into a weird error which i have never encountered before

I have this is my forms.py:

```
class BetaPhoneForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = RegisterHotTable
    fields = ('pracPhone',)

def clean_pracPhone(self):
    pracPhone = self.cleaned_data['pracPhone']

    if pracPhone is None:
        raise forms.ValidationError("This value cannot be empty")
    else:
        if not pracPhone.isdigit():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please enter a valid phone number.")
    return pracPhone
```

So i am cleaning my field with the custom clean method, clean_pracPhone. It works for the part when i leave the value blank and see "This value cannot be empty"

I want the form to display the error "Please enter a valid phone number." instead of the standard "Enter a whole number" when i enter alphabets instead of numbers.

In fact, i realised that this method is not even run when I enter alphabets.

I know i can 'hack' around this by creating a custom charfield and not use the ModelForm but i dont really want to do that.

I also tried self.data instead of self.cleaned_data but it did not work.

Any ideas how I can get this to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the value of `pracPhone` in that method? Does the method run and do you indeed get the string you expected?

Comment: Yes i checked this. The value of `pracPhone` in always blank unless i do the right thing and enter a number. Its like a part the validation is happening before this method is called. I suspect cleaned_data is already validating this. And i dont know how to prevent it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your error message, I am assuming `pracPhone` is represented by an`models.IntegerField` in your models. This means that in your ModelForm, the field is represented by `forms.IntegerField`.

`forms.IntegerField` come with some validations by default:

- required
- invalid
- min_value
- max_value

You should override the default messages for the validation on an `IntegerField` instead.

```
class BetaPhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):

    pracPhone = forms.IntegerField(error_messages={
        "required": "This value cannot be empty.",
        "invalid": "Please enter a valid phone number.",
    })

    class Meta:
        model = RegisterHotTable
        fields = ('pracPhone',)

    def clean_procPhone(self):
        pracPhone = self.cleaned_data['pracPhone']
        # your other validations go here.
        return pracPhone
```

Comment: Is it possible to just have a clean method on the form which filters for fields of a certain type? so all IntegerFields could be cleaned the same way?